# Joint Probability Functions - How to work out distribution of X-Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I dont know how to work out $P(X-Y<a),$ if anyone could help with this it would be appreciated!

Comment: If anyone could help specifically with the 1st question it would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to math SE. It will help us help you if you tell us what you have tried.

Comment: @Surb Indeed this is the same question, but we cannot vote to close since there is no accepted answer to that question. I suggest we focus our efforts on the original question.

Comment: I can see this question has already been asked but I still don't understand how to do it. I have tried seeing what values of fxy are positive but I cant see what values to integrate over to get P(X-Y<a). I'm aware this was sort of answered on the other question but I still don't see how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Use the Law of Total Probability..

$\mathsf P(X-Y<a)=\mathsf E(\mathsf P(X-a<Y\mid X))$